# How to send data from phpmyadmin over https on a debian 9 server with nginx?

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, debian, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've setup a debian 9 server using LEMP stack. On the site http://domain_name I have phpmyadmin setup phpmyadmin is working on https as well, and on http://domain_name:port/api I get response from the sql db hosted on phpmyadmin for an api call. The data comes as raw JSON data.
But over https, I'm not able to send data. What should I do to send the data over https.

Here is a screenshot of the issue

[image: domain send an invalid response]

I created a seperate config file domain.conf, in the /etc/nginx/conf.d dir these are the contents.

```
server{

    server_name domain_name www.domain_name;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_error.log;
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

# Images and static content is treated different
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    expires           360d;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}

location ~ /(libraries|setup/frames|setup/libs) {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
       # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;}

server{if ($host = domain_name) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name www.domain_name ;
return 404; # managed by Certbot}
```

Comment: Maybe [don't install phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin) in the first place?

Comment: thanks for sharing, but i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, so basically this conf file was hosting the phpmyadmin, and i was also trying to host another project on this, thats why it didnt work, instead I created a seperate conf file and connected the phpmyadmin conf file with the new conf file. Another thing to note here is that, you cannot add a port after a domain and that was another reason why this error was prevailing.